# The jQuery val() does not update its value on change

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-selectors, refresh

I change #countrycode value, but $(#countrycode).val() is not refreshed/updated in the "source" option, but the it is updated in the alert

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //List cities with autocompelte
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete(
    {
        source:"autocomplete.php?countrycode=" + $("#countrycode").val(),
        select: function (event, ui) {          

            alert($("#countrycode").val()); //Test the countrycode selector
     }
    });
});
```

The alert shows the updated value, but the same selector (countrycode) used in the source not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I solved it. The source url was being rendered as a string at the first time, that's why it wasnt updating on input changes. So the solution is to pass an anonymous function instead of a string attribute in the source option, and make an ajax call inside the source option. I'd post the code but stackoverflow doesnt let me answer my own questions. Bleh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#countrycode option:selected").prop("selected","false");
$("#countrycode option[value='".$("#countrycode").val()."']").prop("selected","true");
```

it will make the option being select